# Why the static variable is not set to null when the local variable storing that reference is set to null?

Tags: c#, .net, pass-by-reference, static-members

I have following code :

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class InstanceManager
{
    public static Employee employee;

    public static Employee GetEmployee()
    {
        if(employee == null)
        {
            employee = new Employee {Name = "Tom"};
        }

        return employee;
    }
}

public class TestClass
{

    public void Test()
    {
        Employee emp = InstanceManager.GetEmployee();
        var name = emp.Name;
        emp = null;
        var name2 = InstanceManager.GetEmployee().Name;
    }
}
```

In the `Test()` method, local variable `emp` is referencing `InstanceManager.Employee` object. Then, I set `emp` to `null`.

- Doesn't that mean that I am setting `InstanceManager.Employee` to `null`?
- If I debug this code, I find that `employee` static variable of the `InstanceManager` is NOT `null`! Why?

(I was expecting that new Employee object will be created and returned by the `GetEmployee()` method when I call this method after `emp = null;`.)

Comment: `emp` is an instance of `Employee` that's returned by `GetEmployee()`. Setting that object to be null has no impact on the method that returned the object.

Comment: @Jamie Dixon : But `emp` is referencing the object returned by the `GetEmployee()`. Then why does not it set that variable of InstanceManager to null? Does `emp` hold a separate copy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After this line:

```
Employee emp = InstanceManager.GetEmployee();
```

your situation looks like this:

[image]

When you do:

```
emp = null;
```

afterwards, you're not altering the static variable `employee`. You are just setting `emp` to reference another (in this case `null`) "location". More precisely - you're setting it not to point to anything. The static `employee` keeps pointing to where it was. The effect of this line can be visualized like this:

[image]

Comment: I like you. This is the best explainable answer. :)

Answer (score 6):

What you are doing is basically:

```
Employee emp = InstanceManager.GetEmployee();
```

`emp` now is a reference to the `employee` instance

```
emp = null;
```

`emp` is no more a reference to the `employee` instance

```
var name2 = InstanceManager.GetEmployee().Name;
```

`name2` now is a reference to the `employee.Name` instance

You're never setting null to `InstanceManager.employee`. There isn't even a public setter for it btw.

Comment: Are `emp` and `employee` not pointing to the same object? Then why setting `emp` to null does not make `InstanceManager.employee` null? Does `emp` hold separate copy? By the way, there is same behavior if I have public setter.

Comment: @CSharpLearner Setting `emp` to null just _breaks_ the link between `emp` and `employee`. `emp` is really just a _pointer_ to `employee`.

Comment: @ken2k: No, `emp` is not a pointer to `employee`.  Both `emp` and `employee` are pointers straight to the object, not through each other

Answer (score -1):

> Doesn't that mean that I am setting InstanceManager.Employee to null?

No. You are only setting "emp", iself as a local variable to null.

> If I debug this code, I find that employee static variable of the InstanceManager is NOT null! Why?

You would need to implement a public setter for the employee property.  You could just make the property public.

You could also add something like this to the Instance Manager:

```
           public static void ClearEmployee()
            {
                employee = null;
            }
```

As this references the static field explicitly.

Answer (score -1):

"emp" is a new instace of Employee inside Test class. And it do not refer to static variable employee. Because,

```
    Employee emp = InstanceManager.GetEmployee();
```

will get the value and assign to emp.

Conclusion: instance emp (of Test class) and employee(of InstanceManager class) are both different.

Comment: `emp` and `employee` are not two different "instances". They are two different "references" pointing to the same "instance".